# Map from a list to another type - Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: f#

```
let claimsList  =  
          [ {|cType = "uid"; cValue="1"|};
            {|cType = "name"; cValue="N1"|}; 
            {|cType = "sid"; cValue="sid1"|}; 
            {|cType = "email"; cValue="email@N1.com"|}; 
            {|cType = "company"; cValue="Company1"|}]

let email = claimsList
          |> List.tryFind(fun c -> c.cType = "email")
          |> Option.map(fun c -> c.cValue)
let company = claimsList
            |> List.tryFind(fun c -> c.cType = "company")
            |> Option.map(fun c -> c.cValue)
let userId = claimsList
           |> List.tryFind(fun c -> c.cType = "userId")
           |> Option.map(fun c -> c.cValue)

(email, userId, company)
```

I don't like the fact that I am iterating the list multiple times and looks complicated. Is there a way to simplify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to look up claims multiple times, and provided they all have different `cType`s, you could convert the list to a map and then lookup in it:

```
let map = claimsList |> List.map (fun r -> r.cType, r.cValue) |> Map.ofList

let email = map.["email"]
let company = map.["company"]
let userId = map.["uid"]
```

Note that indexing like `map.["email"]` will crash at runtime if the key is not present in the map. This is fine if missing keys "shouldn't normally happen", but if you want to handle this case gracefully, use `Map.tryFind` instead, which will return you an `option`:

```
let email = map |> Map.tryFind "email"
```

Comment: +1 Drives home, that often, basic types (lists, tuples,...) allow for more elegant solutions compared to complex types (structs...).

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I note that this is what OP was looking for, but I still think Reed Copsey's answer is more of an exact answer to the question as formulated, so I upvote both.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid multiple iterations by using a fold, but it doesn't necessarily get less complicated:

```
let claimsList  =  
          [ {|cType = "uid"; cValue="1"|};
            {|cType = "name"; cValue="N1"|}; 
            {|cType = "sid"; cValue="sid1"|}; 
            {|cType = "email"; cValue="email@N1.com"|}; 
            {|cType = "company"; cValue="Company1"|}]

let fld cur (n : {| cType: string; cValue: string |}) =
    let (a,b,c) = cur
    match n.cType with
    | "email" -> (Some n.cValue, b, c)
    | "userId" -> (a, Some n.cValue, c)
    | "company" -> (a, b, Some n.cValue)
    | _ -> cur

claimsList
|> List.fold fld (None, None, None)
```

The main advantage would be eliminating the multiple list iterations, especially if the list was large.

Comment: Thanks Reed. Helpful.